# TextWriter Object not writing full document

Tags: c#, .net, buffer

Hi I have a huge document which I have to read line by line using C# in .NET.
Then perform a operation, and then write that line again.

I am testing the code with a smaller file, the actual file contains 992.482 lines. 
I have tried the following code to test:

```
while (!scenFile.EndOfStream)
{   writer.WriteLine(scenFile.ReadLine().ToString();
}
```

And I could only write 992.474. Then i tried using writer.Flush();

```
System.IO.TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath);
StreamReader scenFile = new StreamReader(filepath2);

while (!scenFile.EndOfStream)
{   (here will go my do-something-function)
         {
          blah blah
         }
    writer.WriteLine(scenFile.ReadLine().ToString();
    writer.Flush();
}
writer.Close();
```

Then, I got all the lines. After inserting this line in the code, I checked, that the only way in that I could obtain is by typing "writer.Flush();" in every iteration. I have tried to insert it in a loop so that I use "writer.Flush();" every certain number of iterations, I have tried numbers from 50 to 500.000, and I can't get all the lines.

The problem is that I will have to perform the operation with a file which is 30 times the actual file, and I need to do it as fast as possible. Does anyone knows why is this and if there is any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried calling `writer.Flush()` right after the `while` loop but before closing the writer?

Comment: Yes, actually I close the writer at the very end of the program. I have editted the code to try to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Ok, you where right. I didnt understand it propperly. I am writing an explanation about it, just copy and paste it with your user name in case you like it, as it was your solution. Sorry about the mistake, and thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

In C# Flush() won't only free the memory reserved for the buffer. It will also "writes it to the underlying stream" ([StreamWriter.Flush()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx)). 
Therefore what I did was just calling `$writer.Flush()` right after the `$while`.

This is my final solution will be

```
    System.IO.TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath);
    StreamReader scenFile = new StreamReader(filepath2);
    int count = 0;
    while (!scenFile.EndOfStream)
    {   (here will go my do-something-function)
     {
      blah blah
     }
     writer.WriteLine(scenFile.ReadLine().ToString();
     count ++;
     if(count == 500000)
     {
         writer.Flush();
         count = 0;
     }
    }
   writer.Flush();
   writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to to flush the stream twice.  You should be able to just flush it before the close...

```
while (!scenFile.EndOfStream)
{   (here will go my do-something-function)
 {
  blah blah
 }
 writer.WriteLine(scenFile.ReadLine().ToString();
}
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

Are you saying that somehow this didn't work?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work because of the size of the file. With the solution I proposed, it works, and I need to be careful as I am working with critical files of 70million lines...

Comment: Huh.  Ok.  Good to know. Back in 2.0 days, a stream would automatically flush when it was full.  Must be some kind of 'nit' in .NET...